# Erro "IntelliSense: 'No additional information available'" no Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

Hoje meu computador travou (por causa do Google Chrome!) e eu precisei reiniciá-lo. O Visual Studio 2012 estava aberto no momento (e eu perdi algumas poucas linhas de código que não havia salvado).

O problema é que após esse evento, o meu IntelliSense simplesmente parou de funcionar! Se eu tento usar (por teclas de atalho, ou menu, ou digitando `std::`[...]) ele exibe a mensagem:

> IntelliSense: 'No additional information available' (See
>   'Troubleshooting IntelliSense in C++ Projects' for further help.)

Só pra constar, já fui lá na [documentação da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235519.aspx) ver a tal "informação adicional" (completamente inútil). Também já reinicializei o VS, já exclui os arquivos `.sdf` e `.suo` do projeto, já exclui a pasta `ReflectedSchemas`... enfim, já fiz todas as sugestões que encontrei [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13376771/2896619) e até algumas outras ideias [desta outra pergunta também no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992983/intellisense-and-code-suggestion-not-working-in-visual-studio-2012-ultimate-rc). E, nada do IntelliSense funcionar.

Alguém já teve esse problema, ou tem mais alguma informação que pode ser útil?

O meu Visual Studio é o Professional 2012 e o projeto é em C++.

Outra informação que pode ser relevante: meu projeto é em Qt, então eu gero os arquivos do projeto do Visual Studio diretamente do `.pro` usando o [`qmake`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html). Também já tentei regerar esses arquivos, mas isso *não resolveu* o problema.

Comment: Instale o 2015 :D

Comment: @bigown Olha, é uma ótima ideia. :)

Comment: Uma dica mais séria agora. Pergunta no SO.

Comment: @bigown Pensei nisso. Tanto que fui lá olhar primeiro. Mas, veja, já foi bastante explorado e o problema é meio bizarro mesmo. Como não é algo absolutamente necessário (e, aliás, também estou instalando o VS 2015 agora) ou impeditivo pra eu continuar meu trabalho, no final escolhi postar aqui porque ao menos fica o link do problema já meio que discutido pra referência futura de outras pessoas.

Comment: Você tentou clicar em Rescan Solution no menu project e depois pressionar Ctrl + Space no codigo

Comment: @FelipeDurar Foi uma boa sugestão. Fui tentar fazer, mas o IntelliSense voltou a funcionar. :/ Mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: Pessoal, eu mesmo votei pra fechar esta pergunta porque o problema não é algo consistente (além de difícil de reproduzir). Depois de reiniciar o computador (por causa da instalação do VS 2015, sugerida pelo @bigown de brincadeira), o IntelliSense voltou a funcionar. Por favor, votem pra fechar também. Optei por não remover porque vai que algum dia alguém tem o mesmo tipo de problema - pelo menos os links podem ser de alguma ajuda.